# How to Compute the All Pairs Shortest Paths: Betweenness Centrality of an Edge e

Tags: graphs-and-networks

By definition, betweenness centrality of an edge e is the sum of the fraction of all-pairs shortest paths that pass through edge e. Traditionally, a(s,t) is the number of shortest (s,t)-paths and a(s,t|e) is the number of those paths passing through edge e. When Mathematica computes EdgeBetweennessCentrality for all-pairs of nodes in a network, especially in a directed graph, is there a way to extract from the results the a(s,t) and a(s,t|e) values used in the calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you can extract them directly from the calculation within `EdgeBetweennessCentrality[]`. I would suggest writing separate code to calculate a(s,t) and a(s,t|e).

Let's make an example graph and print EBC for each edge.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 -> 4, 
   3 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7, 5 <-> 8, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]

TableForm[
 {EdgeList[g], EdgeBetweennessCentrality[g]}\[Transpose]
 , TableHeadings -> {None, {"Edge", "EBC"}}
 ]
```

[image]

Note that as compared to some definitions of EBC, Mathematica takes all possible combinations of vertices in the double sum, so, for example, `EBC(3<->5) = 32` instead of 16 as defined in [this reference](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-1-4419-9863-7_874).

In any case, to calculate a(s,t), I would use the `FindPath[]` function given the length of the shortest path:

```
k = Length@FindShortestPath[g, s, t] - 1;
Length[FindPath[g, s, t, k, All]]
```

a(s,t|e) can be calculated by selecting only those paths that contain a specific subsequence (this assumes directed edges):

```
e = 3 \[DirectedEdge] 4;
Length[Select[FindPath[g, s, t, k, All], 
  SequenceCount[#, {e[[1]], e[[2]]}] > 0 &]]
```

Putting it all together, and accounting for undirected and directed edges, one can print all values of a(s,t) and a(s,t|e) for one of the edges.

```
e = 3 \[DirectedEdge] 4;

TableForm[Table[s = st[[1]]; t = st[[2]];
  k = Length@FindShortestPath[g, s, t] - 1;
  {s, t, e, Length[FindPath[g, s, t, k, All]], 
   Length[Select[FindPath[g, s, t, k, All], 
     If[e[[0]] === UndirectedEdge, 
       SequenceCount[#, {e[[1]], e[[2]]}] > 0 || 
        SequenceCount[#, {e[[2]], e[[1]]}] > 0, 
       SequenceCount[#, {e[[1]], e[[2]]}] > 0] &]]}, {st, 
   Select[Tuples[VertexList[g], 2], #[[1]] =!= #[[2]] &]}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"s", "t", "e", "a(s,t)", "a(s,t|e)"}}]
```

[image]

Note that you will need to use `\[DirectedEdge]` and `\[UndirectedEdge]` to define the edge you want to calculate EBC for.

**Edit**: corrected the code so it works for both directed and undirected graphs.

Comment: Hello mszynisz: This is very creative and clever ... suppose the graph was a directed graph? It doesn't seem as though the code you've written would change. Consider this edge list {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R3 -> R5, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, R4 -> R6, R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, R4 -> R5, R5 -> R6, TX -> R7, TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, R8 -> R6}. Thoughts?

Comment: I think it would be exactly the same. Just use `g = Graph[{TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R3 -> R5, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, R4 -> R6, R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, R4 -> R5, R5 -> R6, TX -> R7, TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, R8 -> R6}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]` and, for example, `e = R1 -> R3;`. Note that for the directed graph, you need to be careful about putting the edge in the correct direction, i.e. `->` rather than `<-`, otherwise `SequenceCount` won't find it in the possible paths.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong, as there's only one way to define directed edges, i.e. `->`. Please ignore my last sentence.

Comment: If I just make the edge 3 to 4 directed 3->4 and leave the rest of the edges undirected as given then the EBC for 3->4 is equal to 5, which does not appear consistent with the table generated by the TableForm code when putting it all together

Comment: You are right. This is because `Subsets[]` doesn't account for ALL possible combinations and instead one should probably use `Tuple[]`. Let me update the answer.

Comment: I just added Tuples and it work wonderfully ... mszynisz your approach was truly brilliant ... many thanks for taking the time ... regards ... prg

Comment: Great! Remember to update the if statement as I did in the edit, otherwise the undirected edges won't be calculated appropriately.

Comment: got it ... thanks very much!